# Getting only the rows who have (at most) 1 column value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that is dynamically built in PHP that selects different combinations of object values using a set of sub-queries that are joined together...so, for example, given the value table:

```
[object_id]    [value_id]
99             1
99             2
99             3
```

I'll get the following results:

```
[object_id]  [a0]   [a1]    [a2]
99           null   null    null  // empty is a valid combination
99           1      null    null
99           null   2       null
99           null   null    3
99           1      2       null
99           null   2       3
99           1      2       3
```

I have a separate table that lists invalid combinations of these object values:

**invalid_values**

```
[object_id] [value]
  99         1
  99         2
```

I'm trying to use the list of invalid values to filter the results of the first query. More specifically, if 2 *or more* `a*` columns exist as a value in `invalid_values`, then the row is not included. So, using this example, `1  2  null  99` and `1  2  3  99` would not be included in the results because both 1 & 2 are in the record and are invalid values together.

I have one query that does what I want, but I fear it's quite inefficient. For each of the subqueries I'm building, I join on another subquery that selects the comma-separated invalid values. I use that to indicate whether the value column is an "incompatible candidate". And at the end of all of this, I add up all of the incompatible candidate columns and if it's 2 or more, they're not returned. Here is an example of the query that is built for "object" id 99:

```
SELECT a0.value_id AS '0', a1.value_id AS '1', a2.value_id AS '2'
FROM (
    SELECT NULL AS value_id, 99 AS object_id, 0 AS incompatible_candidate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value.value_id, value.object_id, CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(value.value_id, pivs.valueIds) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS incompatible_candidate
    FROM value
    JOIN (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(iv.value_id ORDER BY iv.value_id ASC) AS valueIds
        FROM invalid_values iv
        WHERE iv.object_id = 99
        GROUP BY iv.object_id
    ) pivs
    WHERE value.value_id IN (1) AND value.object_id = 99
) AS a0
JOIN (
    SELECT NULL AS value_id, 99 AS object_id, 0 AS incompatible_candidate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value.value_id, value.object_id, CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(value.value_id, pivs.valueIds) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS incompatible_candidate
    FROM value
    JOIN (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(iv.value_id ORDER BY iv.value_id ASC) AS valueIds
        FROM invalid_values iv
        WHERE iv.object_id = 99
        GROUP BY iv.object_id
    ) pivs
    WHERE value.value_id IN (2) AND value.object_id = 99
) AS a1
JOIN (
    SELECT NULL AS value_id, 99 AS object_id, 0 AS incompatible_candidate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value.value_id, value.object_id, CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(value.value_id, pivs.valueIds) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS incompatible_candidate
    FROM value
    JOIN (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(iv.value_id ORDER BY iv.value_id ASC) AS valueIds
        FROM invalid_values iv
        WHERE iv.object_id = 99
        GROUP BY iv.object_id
    ) pivs
    WHERE value.value_id IN (3) AND value.object_id = 99
) AS a2
GROUP BY a0.value_id, a1.value_id, a2.value_id
HAVING SUM(a0.incompatible_candidate + a1.incompatible_candidate + a2.incompatible_candidate) < 2;
```

Can anyone help me with building a more efficient query?

Comment: Have two question: A) So you want all permutation from your original values? B) But only those doesn't have invalid values? But one invalid or all invalid? and why invalid 4 when there isnt value 4?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza a) Yes. b) Yes, but if a permutation has 2 or more invalid values in it, then it should not be included. In other words, invalid values are sets. If a permutation of values is a subset (of count 2 or more) of an invalid set, then it should not be included.


I only included "4" to show that there could be other invalid values, but they aren't active on the object. I'll delete the 4, as it really doesn't add anything to the question.

Comment: I should amend this...I'm already getting permutations with the query I'm building. I want to add support for filtering out results that are invalid, given the definition I've provided above.

Comment: So you are generating all possible combination, and then filter out some "incorrect" values and leave "correct" ones. Why don't generate only correct combinations ? You'll save filtering operation, and it will be faster.

Comment: @krokodilko That's why I'm asking for help. The query I've provided is an example of how I'm currently doing it, which works but feels excessive (case statement, find_in_set, group_concat...)

Comment: I should asked before but is the number of elements in the permutation 3 or is variable?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It's variable; that's where some of the challenge comes from. It shouldn't be too large (almost always below 7). But because it's variable, I found it easier to build the permutation query in PHP rather than SQL. If it were TSQL, I'd use a CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your permutation table this detect invalid rows, the one with two or more invalid values. You can change to `< 2` for valid rows.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/LPMQ93783)**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Permutation P
LEFT JOIN Invalid  x
  ON (P.`a0`, P.`object_id`) = (x.`value_id`, x.`object_id`)
LEFT JOIN Invalid  y
  ON (P.`a1`, P.`object_id`) = (y.`value_id`, y.`object_id`)
LEFT JOIN Invalid  z
  ON (P.`a2`, P.`object_id`) = (z.`value_id`, z.`object_id`)
 AND P.`object_id` = z.`object_id`
WHERE CASE WHEN x.`value_id` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
      CASE WHEN y.`value_id` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
      CASE WHEN z.`value_id` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
      >= 2
;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Well but looks like your current query is fixed for 3 columns too? Anyway you can use a [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to build the query and this one is much easier than yours